Implementation of User Login using Finger prints/ Face recognition in Identity server 4 ASP.Net core
Right now my project is using Identity Server 4 and ASP.net Core, where we do user login using username ad password and we use userManager and siginManager for user login, and all users data is stored in ASPNetUsers table.
I want to implement Finger prints/ Face recognition, Can some one guide me where to start.
Does IdentityServer 4 supports this.
I did some search but did not help me much with IdentityServer4.
Please be so kind and help me here.
Thank you in Advance.

IdentityServer does not care about how you authenticate you users. All you need to do is to tweak the Account/Login page and modify the objects that is passed into the following method:
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);

I would explore the FIDO2 .NET library (WebAuthn) and see if that could help you in implementing Finger prints/ Face recognition.

Login with IdentityServer and doing user biometric are two separate steps that you would need to add to your project in order to achieve what you want.
First you need to choose a Biometric Authentication Provider for example Microsoft Azure Face API.
Refer to Azure Face API: Face Detection & Recognition
You can install from NuGet Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face
After that you need to create BiometricService something similar to
public class BiometricService
{
    private readonly IFaceClient _faceClient;

    public async Task<bool> VerifyFaceAsync(Stream imageStream, Guid userFaceId)
    {
        var detectedFaces = await _faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(imageStream);
        // if identical face found return true else false
    }
}

Extend your existing AccountController for adding this biometric service in the login process
Dependency Inject
public AccountController(
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        BiometricService biometricService)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _biometricService = biometricService;
    }

For example in existing login you can do on successful login
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    // Perform biometric
                    using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(model.BiometricImage))
                    {
                        var isVerified = await _biometricService.VerifyFaceAsync(imageStream, user.FaceId);
                        if (isVerified)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

If you want to do face recognition only. Then you can remove the Password steps from above and use something like.
var faceId = await DetectFaceAsync(model.FaceImage);
 if (faceId != null && await VerifyFaceAsync(user.FaceId, faceId))
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    }
 

private async Task<Guid?> DetectFaceAsync(byte[] faceImage)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(faceImage))
    {
        var faces = await _faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(stream);
        return faces.FirstOrDefault()?.FaceId;
    }
}
    
       
 private async Task<bool> VerifyFaceAsync(Guid userFaceId, Guid detectedFaceId)
    {
 var result = await _faceServiceClient.VerifyAsync(userFaceId, detectedFaceId);
        return result.IsIdentical;
    }


We needed biometric authentication is to skip user providing password. User can either choose password or use biometric in which case password will be empty.

Modified the response. Hope it helps @JackFrost
